# How two build two line of text and one image in one item?

Tags: android, android-listview, listviewitem

i am using java android .
i have a problem in my app and i need some code that can make my item has two lines of texts and one image .
please save me and help .

here is the code for what i tried please make sure that you can help and give your opinion and how i can solve it cause i stucked here.

the main activity

```
  private void setUpView() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     etInput = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText_input);
     Pinput = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     btnAdd = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button_add);
     lvItem = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listView_items);

     itemArrey = new ArrayList<String>();

     itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,itemArrey);
     lvItem.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

     btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             addItemList();
         }
     });

     etInput.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
         public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                 addItemList();
             }
             return false ;
         }
     });
     Pinput.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(keyCode== KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NUM) {
                addItemList();
            }
            return;
        }
    });
 }

 protected void addItemList() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 if (isInputValid(Pinput  )) {

     itemArrey.add(Pinput.getText().toString());
     itemArrey.add(etInput.getText().toString());
     Pinput.setText("");
     etInput.setText("");
    itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

 }   if (isInputValid(etInput  )) {

     itemArrey.add(Pinput.getText().toString());
     itemArrey.add(etInput.getText().toString());
     Pinput.setText("");
     etInput.setText("");
     itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
 }
 protected boolean isInputValid(EditText etInput2 ) {
     // TODO Auto-generatd method stub
     if (etInput2.getText().toString().trim().length()<1) {
         return false;
     } else {
         return true;
     }
 }
```

}

Comment: what you want? a layout with two lines of text and image?

Comment: no i need to change my code that i already post to make my item has two lines of text input and one image @BasimSherif

Comment: can you post your layout file?

Comment: I think your approach is off.  I think you'd do better using a nice layout.xml.  I hope you don't have a teacher that is asking for this sort of approach.

Comment: i cant the stuckoverflow rejected my xml file @BasimSherif..

Comment: you could also try using sites like pastebin.com to create code snippets and link them here...

Comment: (http://pastebin.com/fa38Rpn3) @BasimSherif

Answer (score 0):

If you want a custom view in your ListView I recommend doing one xml layout by yourself and replace `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` in your Adapter call with the new created one.

This would be the easiest way but as I think that you might need more freedom to create/modify the content of the row, I strongly suggest to create your own Adapter extending from BaseAdapter. In the `getView()` method of the adapter you can easily inflate and set up the layout like you want for that row.

Answer (score 0):

Okie... you tag android-listview and list view item. So I think you need list view with image and and Text.
For that you have to use Custom List View.
[See this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)
May be this will help you. and not then pls make your que more clear. :)